# How to deal with orientation change in Open GL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying out Open GL 2 for android. So far I have been able to initialize GLES20 and draw some simple shapes on it. The problem is that I can't find information on how should be GLES20 configured for screen orientation change, as for now I just have a black screen after device rotation. It is even possible for GLSurfaceView to rotate after screen has been rotated, or do I have to do it manually using some matrix?

Open GL init code:

```
object OpenGLBuilder {

val vertexShaderCode =
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
            "}"

val fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}"

var mProgram = -1;
init {
    val vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode)
    val fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode)

    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram().also {

        // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(it, vertexShader)

        // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(it, fragmentShader)

        // creates OpenGL ES program executables
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(it)
    }
}

fun loadShader(type: Int, shaderCode: String): Int {

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    return GLES20.glCreateShader(type).also { shader ->

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode)
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
    }
}
```

}

My shape class:

```
class Triangle(val triangleCoords: FloatArray) {

// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
val color = floatArrayOf(0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f)

private var vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer =
    // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
    ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleCoords.size * 4).run {
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        asFloatBuffer().apply {
            // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
            put(triangleCoords)
            // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
            position(0)
        }
    }
private val COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3
private var positionHandle = 0
private var mColorHandle = 0;

private val vertexCount = triangleCoords.size / COORDS_PER_VERTEX
private val vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4

fun draw(program: Int) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program)

    positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition").also {
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            it,
            COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            vertexStride,
            vertexBuffer
        )
    }

    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "vColor").also{
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0)
    }

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount)

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle)
}
}
```

Then I just create and use single instances of shapes like this:

```
object SceneObjects {
    val triangle1 = Triangle(floatArrayOf(
        0f, 0.5f, 0f,
        -0.5f, -0.3f, 0f,
        0.5f, -0.3f, 0f
    ))

    val square1 = Square2(floatArrayOf(
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0f
    ))

}
```

And GLSurfaceView:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView(context: Context) : GLSurfaceView(context), GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    init{
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2)
        setRenderer(this)
        // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        renderMode = GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY
    }

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(unused: GL10, config: EGLConfig) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(unused: GL10) {
        // Redraw background color
        SceneObjects.triangle1.draw(OpenGLBuilder.mProgram)
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(unused: GL10, width: Int, height: Int) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there's two things you want to do to handle orientation change neatly.

Firstly, by default your OpenGL context and all created objects are destroyed when entering the background. There's an argument that you should just let that happen and add code to recreate all the resources, but if you'd rather have an easy life then just use [setPreserveEGLContextOnPause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(boolean)) and never worry about it again.

You might be thinking "but it was an orientation change, my app didn't enter the background". Well, by default an Android activity gets restarted after an orientation change which might be messing things up. This behaviour is detailed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes). You probably want to use this lot in the manifest for your activity: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"`